# How to get 2 numbers from user input and display the sum in the console? Using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, input, display, addition

```
    import Foundation

    print("Type your age: ")

    if let input = readLine() {
        print("You typed \(input)\n")
    }
```

**I used that before but I dont know how to add them and display it in the console.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/T-Pham/2c14c38cce2cd24eacc83e59558df739

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

print("enter number one: ")
var sum = 0
if let num1 = Int(readLine()!) {
  sum += num1
}
print("enter number two: ")
if let num2 = Int(readLine()!) {
  sum += num2
}

print(sum)
```

start by creating a sum variable, then for each operand, take an input and cast it to an integer which you can add to the sum via the addition assignment operator.

Comment: Pls. edit answer w/brief desc of how it solves problem so it doesn't get deleted on review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Create macos command line tool project.

```
import Foundation

print("Type two input: ")

if let input1 = readLine(), let input2 = readLine(), let value1 = Int(input1), let value2 = Int(input2) {
    print("Sum=\(value1+value2)")
}
```

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

guard let a = Int(readLine()!), let b = Int(readLine()!) else {
  fatalError("expected a number got something else.")
}
print("mul = \(a * b)")
print("sum = \(a + b)")
```

Comment: `fatalError` should be called **very** sparingly - in this situation, I might reccomend printing something like "Did not get the correct number of integers - please try again", as a `fatalError` will instantly crash the app.